# scanf( ) is not taking input in terminal

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter the the table to be printed,...\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b=0;
    while (b>=20)
    {
        printf("%d x %d = %d",a,b,a*b);
        b+=1;
    } 
}
```

The terminal just prints the enter table statement and it stays there forever. I am using vscode and I have switched on `RUN ON TERMINAL`.

Comment: You should type the number to be read via the `scanf()` and hit the Enter (or Return) key. Note that `b>=20` is false when `b=0`, so the loop body won't be executed.

Comment: Another note is that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

Comment: One more note is that you should remove `#include <conio.h>` because it is non-portable and no functions from the header are used here. In other words, it should be removed because it exists only for decreasing portability.

Comment: THANK YOU MR. MIKECAT

Comment: You realize that if your `while` loop executes, it will continue executing until an overflow occurs, don't you?

Comment: As the code is listed, initializing `b = 0` then doing `while(b >= 20)` causes the while loop to be skipped altogether. You likely meant `while(b < 20)`.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as follows:

**1.** It prints `"enter the the table to be printed"`...

**2.** After printing, It waits until you enter a value and attempts to parse it into `int a`.

**3.** Since `b` is set to **0** the while loop will never run and hence the program terminates because the condition for while loop is `b>=20` which is `false`.

PS: I think you need to change the condition in while to be `a<=20` to get what you want to get done.
Also you shouldn't use `conio.h` library, it throws error.

Comment: "it waits for you to input `a`" is a bit misleading. It waits until you enter a value and attempts to parse it into `int a`.

Comment: corrected, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("enter the the table to be printed,...\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b=1;
    while (b<=20)
    {
        printf("%d x %d = %d\n",a,b,a*b);
        b+=1;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```